# Is it possible to write Firefox extension via XUL and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I know that AngularJS is framework for HTML.

XUL(XML user interface language) and HTML have the same underlying processing (can use JavaScript and CSS)

Can AngularJS can intergrate with XUL?

Comment: IIRC, jQuery needed patches before it was usable with XUL (e.g: assumptions about how the global window/document are referenced, and their capabilities). I suspect Angular may have the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093931/is-history-replacestate-broken-for-xul-applications-and-plugins It can work but see the `update` parts in the question for things that can go wrong.

Comment: @HMR that doesn't really count - he is still using angular on HTML, its just embedded in XUL. I think OP wants to use angular on XUL.

Comment: @Naatan I am quite sure that on XUL it won't work because location.replaceState isn't allowed (XUL or chrome type iframe/browser elements). He/me is using a browser element that fills the complete XUL window.

Answer (score 0):

Since XUL is XML, the AngularJS syntax needs to be the XML compliant version:

- add `id="ng-app"` to the root element in conjunction with `ng-app` attribute

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html xmlns:ng="urn:ng" id="ng-app" ng:app="optionalModuleName">
    <div my-directive="exp"></div>
  ...
  </html>
  ```
- Use custom element tags such as `<ng:view>`
- To make CSS selectors work with custom elements, the custom element name must be pre-created with document.createElement('my-tag') regardless of XML namespace.

  ```
  <html xmlns:ng="urn:ng">
  <!-- Needed for ng namespace -->
  <head>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
  // needed to make ng-include parse properly
  document.createElement('ng-include');

  // needed to enable CSS reference
  document.createElement('ng:view');
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
  ng\:view {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }

  ng\:include {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <ng:view></ng:view>
  <ng:include></ng:include>
  ...
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

> the compiler now transparently supports several directive syntaxes. For example while before there was just one way to use ng:include directive: . The new compiler treats all of the following as equivalent:

```
<ng:include src="someSrc"></ng:include> <!-- XHTML element-->
<div ng:include src="someSrc"></div><!-- XHTML attribute-->
<div ng:include="someSrc"></div><!-- XHTML attribute shorthand -->

<div data-ng-include src="someSrc"></div><!-- data attribute-->
<div data-ng-include="someSrc"></div><!-- data attribute shorthand-->

<ng-include src="someSrc"></ng-include> <!-- Expando Element -->
<div ng-include src="someSrc"></div><!-- Expando Attribute-->
<div ng-include="someSrc"></div><!-- Expando attribute shorthand-->

<x-ng-include src="someSrc"></x-ng-include> <!-- Mozilla X-Tag -->

<div class="ng-include: someSrc"></div><!-- Class property-->
```

> This will give template creators great flexibility to consider the tradeoffs between html code validity and code conciseness and pick the syntax that works the best for them.

**References**:

- [How does AngularJS get away with using custom HTML5 element tags and attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665303/how-does-angularjs-get-away-with-using-custom-html5-element-tags-and-attributes)
- [Custom XUL Elements with XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Custom_XUL_Elements_with_XBL)
- [Make New Tags and Widgets with XBL](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/h/2958)
- [AngularJS Guide: IE Compatibility](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/docs-1.0.0/partials/guide/ie.html)
- [Behavior Attachment](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Behavior_Attachment)
- [AngularJS Documentation for Compile: restrict](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile?_escaped_fragment_=#-restrict-)
- [XML Namespaces don't need URIs](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1564)
- [RFC 2141: URN Syntax](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141.txt)
- [urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms875215)