# Create array of attribute values where attribute name ends with certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I'm trying to create an array of element attribute values where the attribute name ends with the string "toselect". I have lots of these elements on the page but I only want the values for the element I clicked on. I don't know if jquery `.attr()` function takes any wild card characters. I'm using jquery but I will also be happy with a pure javascript anwser

I know this doesn't work but I need something similar.

`var attrs[] = $(this).attr('*toselect');`

The html looks like this

```
<div class="someclass" data-firsttoselect="somevalue1" data-secondtoselect="somevalue2" data-thirdtoselect="somevalue3"></div>
```

So the array 'attrs' should contain `{somevalue1, somevalue2, somevalue3}`

Comment: You should probably be using `data-*` attributes, and not your own made up invalid attributes ?

Comment: Just FYI, that HTML is invalid. You cannot add non-standard attributes to elements. Try using `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: I'll do that but I still don't know how to select them

Comment: There's no built in way to select elements based on partial attribute names, you have to iterate and filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, that HTML is invalid. You cannot add non-standard attributes to elements without making the page invalid, which may cause UI and JS issues. Try using `data-*` attributes instead:

```
<div class="someclass" data-firsttoselect="somevalue1" data-secondtoselect="somevalue2" data-thirdtoselect="somevalue3"></div>
```

From there you can create an array of the `*toselect` values by using `map()` and testing the value against a Regex, like this:

```
var data = $('.someclass').data();
var values = $.map(data, function(value, key) {
    if (/toselect$/i.test(key))
        return value;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mds4yjvk/)

Comment: and yet Angular completely depends on non-standard attributes?

Comment: @Alnitak indeed. Most renderers are lenient and will let you away with it, but the HTML is still invalid. Here's a question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665303/how-does-angularjs-get-away-with-using-custom-html5-element-tags-and-attributes

Comment: use of non standard attributes has been common for years , prior to `data-` attributes. Browsers won't crap out, just ignore